# EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat when running ng build

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm getting an ERROR when trying to run `ng build` on my angular 4 app.

```
EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat '<dist directory>'
```

Has anyone encountered this issue?

TIA

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem.

As @Mauricio De La Quintana said, the problem is permission.

In my case (Windows environment), I solved the problem by removing the read-only property from the Repos folder and adding write permission to the Everyone user.

Answer (score 10):

**This probably a permission issue, just restart your IDE with admin permissions!**

In my case I had to restart **VsCode** as **administrator**.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

While running npm run build - I received error

Open Task Manager -> Select Chrome - > End Task
-> Select VSCode -> End Task

Opened the Project again -> Run npm run Build ---> worked for me

Comment: I spent way too long on this problem until this answer reminded me I should just restart my computer. turned out it worked, thank you

Answer (score 6):

This has happened in my ASP.NET projects. For me this has happened for one of two reasons.

1. This can be a permission problem so you need to run Command Prompt as Admin.

   a. Press <kbd>win</kbd> to open the start menu. Type in cmd to search for Command Prompt.

   b. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> to launch Command Prompt as administrator.
2. This can happen when you build your web project in Visual Studio(or another IDE) and it is currently running.

   a. This is a simple fix click the stop debugging and then try 'ng build' again.

Comment: It was the 2nd issue with me. I had another command shell open running my app and didn't realize it. Silly simple mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Just restarted the VSCode and ran in admin. That solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this problem when running IISNODE...

Solution: Ensure that AppPool Identify from IIS has read permissions all the way from root of harddrive to website files.

Full answer is here https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/247

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue while running a build on windows at the same time WSL was running in the directory. The issue was resolved by closing the WSL terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Simply follow these steps

> 1. Restart `VS Code`
> 2. run `npm run build`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a permission problem, when you do ng build you also delete the previous files. I suggest using

```
sudo chown -R youruser /pathAngularApp
```

Comment: I do think it's a permission problem but I already run the command with admin rights (I'm using Windows btw).

Comment: I think that you can select your node modules folder and go to the files's properties and check and uncheck the only the "read-only" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it was related to what @goku_da_master commented, I had the vueJs application running even when my VsCode stopped, I figured it out from the task manager and fixed it like this:

> - I opened the task manager
> - I searched if Node.js was running
> - Right click on the Node.js process
> - Finish Task
> - "npm run dev" again

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. The fix for me was to install the correct node version that the project was requiring (an older one), then closing all terminal windows in VS Code, and relaunching VSC.

To switch node versions, I installed nvm and had to make sure the default alias was pointing towards the exact node version I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by moving the project to a new directory. It is better not in C disk.

Answer (score 0):

IN 2023 you can just try to use the terminal without Vscode, it seems Vscode block the code by some internal processes like addons or extentions. Use just an external terminal.

Check this comment for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/76500431/9026103

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if the build folder is being used in another process. Example serves -s build may be running on the machine and does not allow running npm run build on the application. Close the process in use of the build folder and try again!

Answer (score -4):

> **Error : Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\Administrator'**

We encountered this error after the Windows update.

This Solution worked for me;

1. Go to `C:\Users\Administrator`
2. Rename the file `NTUSER.DAT` as `NTUSER-old.DAT`