# Error in React Native when running firebase deploy

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-native

When I'm running "firebase deploy" to update my codes, this error showing it into my project terminal. I search about this, but didn't resolve it in my case. So I decided to ask in Stack Overflow.

This is the error I get:

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'D:\React Native Projects\repeatproject\android\firebase-debug.log'
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! repeatproject@0.0.1 start: `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the repeatproject@0.0.1 start script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-11-17T12_26_06_323Z-debug.log

This is my environment: functions/package.json

```
{
"name": "functions",
"description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
"scripts": {
"serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
"shell": "firebase functions:shell",
"start": "npm run shell",
"deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
"logs": "firebase functions:log"
},
"dependencies": {
"@google-cloud/storage": "^1.7.0",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
"firebase-functions": "^2.1.0",
"uuid-v4": "^0.1.0"
},
"private": true
}
```

Guys, feel free to ask for more of my codes! Thank you.

Comment: Not sure and i can't figure out something to try to reproduce it, but i'm sure i had quite a few of those errors.  I think i get these when there is something wrong with my Typescript code, not with the syntax but let say for example that it would detect that i was using some kind of loop instead of an other one ...  Are you sure you don't see any lines in the log that talk about error in your code?

Comment: Yea i'm sure all of my codes. I already triple check it

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645951/eperm-operation-not-permitted-lstat-when-running-ng-build it seems it would be a permission problem just search for this on Google : Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat

Comment: Does not work for me haha