# Appium is not installing

Tags: node.js, appium

I installed appium on windows through command. But when I tried to run, it shows error.

> C:\Users\Admin>appium
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
> throw err;
> ^
> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js'

Error after installing appium

Image of console
[image]

Comment: What command did you use?

Comment: @DaemonBeast npm install -g appium

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using?

Comment: @DaemonBeast v12.18.2

Comment: Try `npm uninstall -g appium` then `npm install -g appium`.

Comment: @DaemonBeast It didn't work. I got some err and warn, I edited my question and added the error and warning there maybe it would help to identify the problem.

Comment: @DaemonBeast sorry now its edited

Comment: Try `npm install -g --force appium`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645951/eperm-operation-not-permitted-lstat-when-running-ng-build

Comment: @DaemonBeast Thanks it worked (npm install -g --force appium). Could you add this to the answer so that I cant mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @bravemaster Thank you for your response, but the problem has been solved. By DaemonBeast by running command "npm install -g --force appium".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installation is failing because files it needs to create already exist. You need to pass the `--force` flag when installing to overwrite these files:

```
npm install -g --force appium
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your node.js by downloading the installer package of node js